# Core Data - partial data loss when relaunching app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a Core Data app with a single model consisting of several entities. For the purposes of this question, let's call the model "Person" and have the entities "name" (string), "age" (int), "occupation" (string), and "description" (string).

As an example, I may add a new Person. I set their name, age, occupation, and description. I confirm that the context has been updated by checking the contents of the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` userInfo. The context is then saved and persisted to disk (confirmed through both logging and querying the SQLite db).

At this point, I can edit any of my Person objects and all entities can be modified, added, deleted, etc., and all changes are confirmed to change the context with `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` and confirmed to be persisted to disk via logging and querying SQLite - everything works as expected.

However, "occupation" and "description" do not persist after relaunching the app. They are not set as `transient` (however they are "optional"), and the main context is saved (sometimes several times) after they are set. More so, if I quit the app, before opening it again, I can query the SQLite db and confirm that the changes still exist on disk.

When the app is reopened, I can confirm that all is the same on disk as it was when I quit. *However*, when I initialize Core Data in my App Delegate, `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` notifies me that something has changed. For some reason, "occupation" and "description" have disappeared. They haven't been set to null, they've been set to zero-length strings. Therefore, next time something happens that triggers a save, "occupation" and "description" are set to zero-length strings and disappear. This all happens just on launch - I do not access a view controller or anything else that even queries for those specific fields. I do, however, show a view controller that does require a fetch request that populates a UITableView that displays the People objects, although it does not specifically display either of the entities in question.

There is a lightweight Core Data Model migration from Person 1 to Person 2, however, when switching back to Person 1, this problem persists, leading me to believe it is not the migration which is an issue.

I'm asking for recommendations on where to start troubleshooting this issue. I can't post code - I have no idea where in my app the problem is occurring. I've tried to troubleshoot as much as possible with confirming when changes occur in the context and how that compares with what is on disk, I just don't know where to go from here. I don't know why these entities (and only some of them) are disappearing. How would someone start troubleshooting this kind of issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: in your `Person` managed object model, create custom setters for the problematic properties and add breakpoints. If these are in fact being modified when your app restarts you should see that happening through those methods, and the stack trace will give you a hint about who is calling it.

Comment: Also what happens if you rename the properties to something different? Try `occupation1` and `description1` and see if the problem persists, then go from there. I'm pretty sure you are not supposed to use `description` as an attribute name because it overrides `description` implemented by `NSObject`. [edit] Yup see here the documentation says you're discouraged from overriding `description` as the results may be unpredictable https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/LifeofaManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH16-SW1

Comment: In the entity in question, override `validateValue:forKey:error`, and add conditional code that logs when `value` is an empty string and `key` is one of the troublesome fields.  Now, put a breakpoint on the logging line and you'll be able to see, via the backtrace, exactly who is setting the field to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the guidance of @Rog and @Avi, I was able to both set up custom setters for the properties in question and override `validateValue:forKey:error`, and set breakpoints in each. From here, I was able to see the calling methods and diagnose the issue correctly.

The actual issue was that I was misunderstanding that `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` is called for each object when Core Data is initialized, where I was under the impression it would only be called when an object is initially created (once and only once). The problematic code was in `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`.

Thank you for your help!